# Add Store Name to OpenCart 2 admin order list page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, vqmod

I am trying to add the store name in the order list on OpenCart. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862947/add-a-custom-field-on-opencart-admin-order-info-page) and have tried to modify it to show store name but it doesn't work. It just displayed no results, so no orders show now.

Here is my code:

```
       <modification>
  <id><![CDATA[Show Store Name]]></id>
    <version>1</version>
    <vqmver>2.X</vqmver>
<author>author</author>

<file name="admin/view/template/sale/order_list.tpl">

    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
        <a href="<?php echo $sort_order; ?>"><?php echo $column_order_id; ?></a>
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        <!-- custom -->
                <td class="text-left">
                    <?php echo $text_store_name; ?></a>
                </td>

        <!-- custom -->
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $order['order_id']; ?></td>
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        <td class="text-left"><?php if(!empty($order['column_store'])){echo "CU".$order['column_store'];} else{echo "  ";} ?></td>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>

</file>

</modification>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue you're having is that in 2.3.0.2, the function `getOrders()` in `admin/model/sale/order.php` does not query `*` the way the `getOrder()` function does.  When I added the field `store_name` to the `$sql` query in `getOrders()`, displaying the store worked.

I didn't write an vqMod, I just modified `admin/view/template/sale/order_list.tpl`, `admin/model/sale/order.php`, `admin/controller/sale/order.php` as follows:

`view/template/sale/order_list.tpl`:  (obviously you should modify the language file instead of hardcoding; this is just a POC)

```
103,107d102
< <!-- bof mod -->
<                   <td class="text-right">
<                      Store Name
<                   </td>
< <!-- eof mod -->
147d141
<                   <td class="text-left"><?php echo $order['store_name']; ?></td>
```

`admin/model/sale/order.php`:

```
173c173
<       $sql = "SELECT store_name, o.order_id, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, (SELECT os.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS order_status, o.shipping_code, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, o.date_added, o.date_modified FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o";
---
>       $sql = "SELECT o.order_id, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, (SELECT os.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS order_status, o.shipping_code, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, o.date_added, o.date_modified FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o";
```

`admin/controller/sale/order.php`:

```
214d213
<               'store_name'      => $result['store_name'],
```

Comment: How would just one line of code in the controller add the store name to the order list? thanks for the help

Comment: No sorry. I wanted to have a new column in the order list to be the store name and the value to be the store name for each order.. Does this make sense? Thanks

Comment: If you go to Sales > Orders - this is where the order list is. It is where all your orders are shown. Not a multistore. I use OpenBay and on the order it shows if the sale is on ebay or the store itself so I would like this to be shown when I look at all the orders - in the order itself it shows ebay on the store name so want this to be shown in the columns on the order list .

Does this make sense?

Thanks

Comment: OpenBay doesnt setup a new store.. It just changes the name in the Order details tab on the order. it goes: Order ID, Invoice No and then Store Name: bla bla bla.. THis is the value I need to get in the previous window (order list) Am I making sense?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very kind. Excuse my ignorance but what do the numbers mean at the top? "103,107d102" - I guess it is line 103? I am ok to work out where to put it in the order_list file but not so great on sql coding so not sure where to put this as on line 173 it says: "   if ($implode) {
    $sql .= " WHERE (" . implode(" OR ", $implode) . ")";
   } else {". ----- Is this where I should put it - can you be so kind to put the lines of code before where this should go so I can search for the code in the file and work out to paste the code?

Thanks

Comment: I Think I know what to do. I should replace the bottom line with the top one on model/sale/order.php ? I have done this and uploaded to site. I cannot see any changes. The strange thing is that I cant even see the html (<td> Store Name </td> Even when I inspect the page. I have cleared the vqmod cache and still nothing.

Comment: For the diffs, these are the changes from the new (fixed file) to the old (original file).  So the first block is a 3 line insertion starting at line 103, then a 1 line insertion starting at line 147.  For the lack of visible changes: Perhaps your browser is caching the page?  Can you use Developer Tools to prevent caching and test again?